# Java pdf clown vs apache pdf box

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfclown

I search for a free Java Library to analyse pdf's in a commercial programm.

Which is the better library to do data mining in a pdf by counting different words and detect titles ?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Until now i just searching which one can better read titles and text formats and is in free use for a commercial programm i hoped that you can tell me your experience  and assesments with the librarys

Comment: Asking for "experiences" invites opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDFBox is going to be a great Java Library for PDFs. Currently, the latest version is not stable yet, by provides great solutions. The documentation is cute, so if you want to do easy stuff, you won't waste too much time for learning.